# Extract tokens including a single angle bracket

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to extract a token that includes an angle bracket, e.g. `123K>L` but the `>` character cannot be parsed as an angle bracket. For example, if I have the following, it will not work:

```
pattern=[(r'[0-9]+[a-z]>[a-z]','PATTERN')]
```

Or if I use the backslash to void the role of the angle bracket:

```
pattern=[(r'[0-9]+[a-z](\>)[a-z]','PATTERN')]
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is not with the angle bracket; `>` does not have any special meaning when used in a pattern like that.

Instead, the problem is that the character set `[a-z]` only matches the lowercase letters `a` through `z`.  Your sample string of `123K>L` however has uppercase letters.  To match these as well, use the character set `[A-Za-z]`.

Demo:

```
>>> import re
>>> re.match('[0-9]+[A-Za-z]>[A-Za-z]', '123K>L')
<_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(0, 6), match='123K>L'>
>>>
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems your string has uppercase letters which is likely the issue, try the following:

```
[0-9]+[A-Z]>[A-Z]
```

Or you could simply use the inline case-insensitive modifier to allow both.

```
(?i)[0-9]+[a-z]>[a-z]
```